# Node.js socket.io emit не работает с кириллицей

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

имеется два варианта кода **на сервере**:

```
socket.on('list', function(){
    socket.join('list');
    socket.emit('init', "Test");
}
```

И второй:

```
socket.on('list', function(){
    socket.join('list');
    socket.emit('init', "Тест");
}
```

Разница лишь в том, что в первом варианте "Test" написан латиницей, а во втором - кириллицей. При этом вариант с кириллицей срабатывает в одной из пяти раз, он просто не всегда отправляет этот "emit", но в "on" на сервере действия срабатывают. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина.

Comment: Может быть в кодировке. Убедитесь, что у вас utf-8 во всех файлах. А вообще, socket.io довольно комплексный модуль, предоставляющий кучу уже никому не нужных на сегодняшний день костылей. Советую использовать что-нибудь более простое и надёжное, например [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf пробовал и кодировку менять с помощью utf8.decode(), не помогло. Причём один из пяти раз же работает, и когда приходит, то нормальный русский текст

Comment: Не думаю, что кто-то сможет помочь вам с этой проблемой лучше чем разработчик. Если баг имеет место быть, то сообщите о нём [здесь](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues).

Comment: `socket.join('list');`

Comment: @qwabra Не понял. ?

Answer (score -1):

> @qwabra Не понял. ? – Alexey 2 часа назад

если вы хотите протестировать `socket.emit('init', "кириллический текст");`

то встаёт вопрос, почем вы это делаете внутри `socket.on('list'`
ещё и после `socket.join('list`
вы уверены что подключение к комнате происходит синхронно?
вы уверены, что ваш `list` с клиента приходит?
вы уверены, что у сокетио не сносит крышу при подключении к комнате, если клиент уже в ней?

```
// socket.on('list', function(){ // убрать
//     socket.join('list');      // убрать 
    socket.emit('init', "Test"); // оставить лишь то, что тестируете
// }                             // убрать
```

@Alexey, вот что я хотел сказать.

да, версию ноды и библиотеки укажите в вопросе!

---

у меня всё работает.

- "socket.io": "2.1.1"
- "node": "10.1.0"

back

```
io.on('connection', s =>
{
    let counter = 0
    console.log('\nconnection\n');
    let Rrlk = () =>
    {
        counter++
        // s.emit('qwabra', "Test " + counter)
        // s.emit('qwabra', "ТЕСТИРУЮ " + counter)
        s.emit('qwabra', 'ТестиРую ' + counter)
        // s.emit('qwabra', `test_ИРУЮ ${counter}`)
        console.log(counter);
        !(counter % 5) && console.log('');
    }
    let interval = setInterval(Rrlk, 1200)
    s.on('disconnect', () =>
    {
        clearInterval(interval)
    })
})
```

front

```
let old = null
let counter = 0
socket.on('qwabra', d =>
{
    counter++
    console.log(counter, d)
    if (old && old !== counter - 1)
        console.error('old !== LioPgh - 1', old !== counter - 1, 'old', old, 'LioPgh', counter)
})
```

---

Comment: Как я уже сказал, всё работает, если писать не русскими буквами, так что join и остальное здесь не причём. внутри "on" я делаю действие, потому что действия такие - Пользователь заходит на страницу со списком, отправляет на сервер, сервер его добавляет в комнату и отправляет ему обновления списка и сразу отдает тот список, что уже есть, чтобы пользователь посмотрел, что было до этого

Comment: Попробую и напишу версии позже

Comment: Пока что я решил это костылем - На сервере закодировал в base64, а на фронте раскодировал. Таким образом получилось передать русские символы без проблем, но костыль очень серьезный